# How to communicate between 3 nested components of blazor C# in two-way binding asp.net core (from parent to its grandchild vice versa)

Tags: c#, blazor

**I need to communicate between 3 components in blazor in the code behind.**

- Parent component has a **(submit button)** button click event, in that **code behind I need to call the child-1 component** by passing some parameter and waiting for its response as **bool value in return**.
- The child-1 component communicate with child-2 by invoking the dialog popup with **confirm button**.
- When user clicks the confirm button in child-2 component I need to send response back to child-1 as **status = true else false.**
- Then the child-1 returns the response from child-2 to the parent as **status=true**

> **Note :** *The Child-1 component acts as intermediate it doesn't have any UI elements*

***This is the concept, I don't how to call the child-1 component in the code behind of parent***

**Example :** [In Parent Component]

```
<button @onclick="callChildOne">Submit<button/>

void callChildOne(){
// i need to call child-1 here and pass the parameter status
// i need help in writing this code
}
```

**[REFER THIS IMAGE FOR BETTER UNDERSATNDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8fcX.png)**

Comment: Create a common object for the shared data set as a scoped DI service and events when that data changes.  See my answer to this question which explains this approach -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773187/blazor-issues-with-using-cascading-parameters-for-passing-values/72774892#72774892

Comment: In addition to @MrCakaShaunCurtis, I can recommend you to check the `Fluxor` library, it could be a great choice if you have some other similar cases in your project.

Comment: Actually, what @Shaun said is a way of creating services and injecting using DI but in my case, I need to have a component and consume its methods without any services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the case and came up with answer in terms of blazor. Refer below example

**Child2.razor**

```
@code{//some code}
```

**Child1.razor**

```
//No UI, only methods in code behind
    @code{
       public void Show()
       {
        // TODO actual implementation for calling child 2 component
       }
    }
```

**Parent.razor**

```
<button @onclick="callChildOne">Submit<button/>

@*Add a @ref to the component *@
<Child1 @ref="childObj"></Child1 >

@code {
    //Hold the reference to the component
    private Child1 childObj;

    // Call the public methods of the component
    private void callChildOne() => childObj.Show();    
}
```

This is how I mapped relationship with 3 components without any service. I read this example from blog of [Blazor here](https://www.meziantou.net/calling-public-methods-on-blazor-component-from-another-component.htm)